# Способом отключить в bash захват control+c?

Tags: bash

Есть bash внутри которого запускается другой bash.
Мне кнопками control+c нужно завершить bash самый глубокий по вложенности, но завершается самый первый, а последние до конца работу этим самым не выполняют. Последние запускают в себе программы (файлы исполняемые), и по моей идеи, control+c должен лишь в самом последнем bash выключить программы, далее все лесенкой будут завершать свою работу.

Comment: Nohup + kill можно, или ctrl+z и kill

Comment: Когда вы нажимаете `Ctrl-C` в терминале, то система посылает signal SIGINT **всем процессам**, которые в данный момент связаны с данным терминалом (точнее тем процессам, для которых этот терминал является управляющим (видимо, в вашем  случае с "окошком" из которого вы запускаете скрипт)). Вообще, тема большая и сложная. Попробуйте начать [с этого](https://linux.die.net/Bash-Beginners-Guide/sect_12_01.html#sect_12_01_01)

Comment: Вам стоит также понять, что такое *управляющий терминал*, т.е. другими словами терминал, который принимает эти самые нажатия.

Answer (score 2):

Перехватывать сигнал `SIGINT` отправляемый командой `cntr + c` можно командой `trap`
Изначально сигнал передается сначала скрипту последней вложенности:

Создадим 2 скрипта
1.sh с содержанием:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'echo "Перехвачен сигнал cntr + c 1.sh"' SIGINT
/tmp/test.sh
echo "finish task"
```

test.sh с содержанием:

```
#! /bin/sh
trap 'echo "перехвачен ctrl + c test.sh"' SIGINT
sleep 1m
echo "finish test.sh"
```

Запускаем скрипт 1.sh и в момент выполнения отправляем сигнал SIGINT

```
./1.sh
^Cперехвачен ctrl + c test.sh
finish test.sh
Перехвачен сигнал cntr + c 1.sh
finish task
```

Как видим первым получил сигнал дочерний скрипт test.sh, так как мы скриптом перехватываем сигнал остановился только sleep и скрипт продолжил свое выполнение.

Теперь убираем из test.sh строку перехвата сигнала и при передаче сигнала SIGINT, скрипт test.sh останавливает свое выполнение, а 1.sh продолжает работать далее.

```
./1.sh
^Cперехвачен cntr + c 1.sh
finish task
```

---

при вызове trap возможно выполнять функции, запускать скрипты, описывать действия на разные виды сигналов остановки. Более подробно можно прочитать в интернете.

---

Дополню что команда trap может обработать большинство сигналов остановки за исключением SIGKILL